# Azure Media Player not working on Android Chrome

Tags: android, media-player, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use Azure Media Services, but have some trouble below.
I saw azure media player site (http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html)
on Android Chrome.
With mobile network, any samples can not playback, and Diagnostics show "videoTag: suspend, currentTime: 0".
But, connecting to WiFi, video can playback properly.

Does anyone know what causes this problem and how to solve ?

[Additional info.]
Android version:5.0.2
Chrome version:48.0.2564.95

With mobile network,
Chrome: not work
Opera: not work (same as Chrome)
Firefox: work well

With WiFi,
Chrome: work well
Opera: work well
Firefox: work well

---

With mobile (3G/4G) network, browser console throws following error message.

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is simply timing out here. Is the browser console throwing an error messages?

Alternatively, can you test this in something like the **Ripple emulator** and change the connection settings between wifi and 3/4g?

Comment: Hi, Dave. Thank you for your comment. I added the error message on browser console to my original question.

Comment: Hmm that is peculiar. I haven't seen that before. It would be odd that the video would stop playing simply from scrolling, though.

Comment: This error may be unrelated to the problem. I made test web using azure media player. On Chrome for Windows, mpeg-dash video playback properly with preload="auto". While, video doesn't playback with preload="none". I've already set prefetch always on Chrome for android, but I'm still in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of AMP 1.6.3 this issue is resolved. We also had this issue on some android devices. Now it's working!

Comment: Hi, Niels. I found that video playbacked properly with AMP 1.6.3. Many thanks!